# Wordpress is using single.php and page.php instead of index.php for home page

Tags: php, wordpress

My Home pages(index.php) are not being loaded by index.php, instead they are being loaded in page.php or single.php
I'm not able to figure out the reason for this.

Comment: You have a static homepage - read up on the hierchy of templates

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Settings->Readings` you have set a page as home page. If you set a home-page and blog-page form `Settings->readings` then home-page will show form `page.php` and blog will show from `index.php`. If you want a default and permanent structure for front-page/home-page you may set `front-page.php`, It will show on home-page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the WordPress [hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/) out. If you want it to load index.php you have to delete single.php for single posts and page.php for pages.